# What are https methods?

Tags: .net, web-services

I am using asmx webservice.   Due to requirement, we have changed http to https.

Now i have basic clarification about request methods **HttpGet** and **HttpPost**.
Is any methods related to https.  Like **HttpsGet** and **HttpsPost**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During http to https transition, you doesn't have any changes to do in the code side.

> HttpGet and HttpPost remain the same either in http or https

Why not, the only change you can do, is redirect http to https in web config with rewrite rules

Comment: Do you confirm that the same HttpGet and HttpPost methods also used in https?

Answer (score 2):

> HttpGet,HttpPost  in asmx translates to HTTP [Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) so no change required.

For asmx the [protocols elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ccbk8w5h(v=vs.85).aspx)  is basically used to associate request data with a Http method.when you enable https,you are basically change the transport only So no change required in your application code for http methods